# Testing to see if a value exists in a nested JSON array

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I have a SQL 2016 table that contains a column holding JSON data. A sample JSON document looks as follows:

```
{
    "_id": "5a450f0383cac0d725cd6735",
    "firstname": "Nanette",
    "lastname": "Mccormick",
    "registered": "2016-07-10T01:50:10 +04:00",
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Cote Collins",
        "interests": [
          "Movies",
          "Movies",
          "Cars"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ratliff Ellison",
        "interests": [
          "Birding",
          "Birding",
          "Chess"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "William Ratliff",
        "interests": [
          "Music",
          "Chess",
          "Software"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Nanette! You have 4 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  }
```

I want to pull all documents in which the `interests` array of each `friends` object contains a certain value. I attempted this but got no results:

```
Select *
From <MyTable>
Where 'Chess' IN (Select value From OPENJSON(JsonValue, '$.friends.interests'))
```

I should have gotten several rows returned. I must not be referencing the interests array correctly or not understanding how SQL Server deals with a JSON array of this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Interests` is a nested array, you need to parse your way through the array levels. To do this, you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `OPENJSON()`. The first `CROSS APPLY` will get you the friend names and the JSON array of interests, and then the second `CROSS APPLY` pulls the interests out of the array and corrolates them with the appropriate friend names.  Here's an example query:

```
Select [name]
From #MyTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonValue, '$.friends')
WITH ([name] NVARCHAR(100) '$.name',
        interests NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(interests)
WITH (Interest NVARCHAR(100) '$')
WHERE Interest = 'Chess'
```

Comment: Yikes, that was a lot more complicated than I thought. But it works. Thank you.